# How can I strip escape codes from a string in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

The original string is passed as:

```
FileSystems\/\1K-blocks=5036316, FileSystems\/\Available=3295944, FileSystems\/\Filesystem=/dev/cciss/c0d0p2, FileSystems\/\Use%=32%
```

What I need as an output is:

```
/ 1K-blocks=5036316, / Available=3295944, / Filesystem=/dev/cciss/c0d0p2, / Use%=32%
```

but trying to delete the '\' with a regex is giving me all kinds of headaches. I keep ending up with:

```
Fi eSys ems/☺K-b o ks=5036316  Fi eSys ems/Avai ab e=3295944  Fi eSys ems/Fi esy
s em=/dev/  iss/ 0d0p2  Fi eSys ems/SE%=32%
```

Perl is apparently seeing it a a control or escape code and really screwing it up.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: is your input data utf8?

Answer (score 3):

I would use different delimiters (other than /) to make the regex a little easier on the eyes:

```
s!FileSystems\\/\\!/ !g
```

Answer (score 0):

These two lines should do it:

```
s/FileSystems\\//g;
s/\\/ /g;
```

Answer (score -1):

Using diff. delimiters will make this much less confusing.

```
$line =~ s!FileSystem\\/\\!/\s!g
```

would do the trick

Comment: You cannot use \s in the replacement string.